# Wrong number of indices inside []; expected '1'

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following array:

```
string[] list1 = new string[2] { "01233", "THisis text" };
string[] list2 = new string[2] { "01233", "THisis text" };
string[] list3 = new string[2] { "01233", "THisis text" };
string[] list4 = new string[2] { "01233", "THisis text" };

string[][] lists = new string[][] { list1, list2, list3, list4 };
```

I am trying to see the array values using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lists.GetLength(0); i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < lists.GetLength(1); j++)
     {
        string s = lists[i, j]; // the problem is here
        Console.WriteLine(s);
     }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The problem is `lists[i, j];` is underlined and causing this error message : `Wrong number of indices inside []; expected '1'`

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Side note: use a `std::vector` or a `std::list`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lists` is not a 2D array. It is an array of arrays. Hence the syntax `lists[i][j]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < lists[i].Length; j++)
     {
        string s = lists[i][j]; // so
        Console.WriteLine(s);
     }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Note how `Length` is checked for an array of arrays. However, as others have said, why not use `foreach`? You need two nested `foreach` loops for an array of arrays.

---

Another option is to actually use a 2D array, a `string[,]`. Declared like:

```
string[,] lists = { { "01233", "THisis text" },
                    { "01233", "THisis text" },
                    { "01233", "THisis text" },
                    { "01233", "THisis text" }, };
```

Then you can use two `for` loops like you have, with `lists[i,j]` syntax, or **one** single `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (with explanation). It is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you have list of lists and not 2D array. To get element from your datastructure you have to use it like this:

```
lists[i][j]
```

and your full code would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < lists[i].Length; j++)
     {
        string s = lists[i][j];
        Console.WriteLine(s);
     }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

But actually, in your case it's better to use `foreach`:

```
foreach (var l in lists)
{
     foreach (var s in l)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
     }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
for (int i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lists[i].Length; j++)
    {
        string s = lists[i][j];
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach instead

```
foreach(var array in lists )
    foreach(var item in array)
    {
    //item
    }
```